# How to apply JQuery unveil on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery unveil to show images and for the static images the code is working well. But as we know, the unveil event triggers on scroll. For the image that is added dynamically, the loader image doesn't get replaced by the actual image ( in fact, the event does not get triggered).

```
function replaceResumeImage () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.fusion-layout-column-modified .lib-res-image.unveilimg').unveil(400, function () {
      $(this).load(function () {
        this.style.opacity = 1
        $(this).removeClass('loader-img')
      })
    })
  }, 0)
}
```